# C++ DirectX11 2d Game: Stopping enemy sprites moving over each other?

Tags: c++, collision

I am using `IntersectsWith(this->boundingBox))` method to detect collisions between sprites and player. I want to somehow be able to use this method in detecting my enemy sprites that collide with each other, and when they do to make sure they don't move over one another.

All of the enemy sprites follow the player.

MainGame.cpp

Loops over each enemy in the vector and does the update loop:

```
for (auto &enemyMobsObj : this->enemyMobs)
        {

            enemyMobsObj->Update(tickTotal, tickDelta, timeTotal, timeDelta, windowBounds, this->ship, this->firstBoss,
                this->enemyMobs, this->bullets, this->missiles, NULL, "NULL", "NULL");
        }
```

Here is what I tried before to stop each sprite moving over each other:

EnemyMobOne::Update:

```
int nextEnemy;

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyMobOne.size(); i++)
    {
        nextEnemy = i + 1;
        if (nextEnemy < enemyMobOne.size())
        {
            //Deal with mobs collision
            if (enemyMobOne[i].boundingBox.IntersectsWith(enemyMobOne[nextEnemy].boundingBox))
            {
                enemyMobOne[i].position.x = enemyMobOne[nextEnemy].position.x - enemyMobOne[i].boundingBox.Width;
            }
        }
    }
```

However this makes each enemy sprite obviously stick to each other, which doesn't look right, it also makes them teleport.

Anyone know the correct code to stop them moving over each other? Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's better to do the collision checking when you actually try to move the enemies toward the player. That way they simply stay where they are when they would collide. Your solution puts the enemies to a new position which has no relation to their last position. Also, if you move an enemy in your collision check, you will have to check every other collision again, you might have created a new collision by moving the enemy. This could lead to infinite collisions. Therefore it's much easier to stop the enemy from moving instead of resetting them after they have already moved.

Comment: Sidenote: `this` is rarely needed. If this is your programming style and it's easier for you this way, fine. But usually you don't need to specify `this` in front of every member. It makes the code much longer than it has to be.

Comment: So what you're saying is that when they collide, stop the enemy sprites from moving? I tried this but the problem with this is that I need the sprites to follow the player at all times (main part of my game). Also I do use m_ instead of this-> now. I am new to C++ so that's why I was using this->.

Comment: I'm no expert at game programming, maybe someone else has a better idea. But what do you want to do when there is a collision? You don't want them to be on top of each other so there may be situations in which an enemy simply cannot move because there is an obstacle blocking it at the moment. Instead of stopping them from moving at all you can also try to move them as close as possible to the next colliding enemy. The main issue I see here is that you always move `enemy[i]` to the left of `enemy[nextEnemy]`, but how do you know on which side `enemy[i]` was when the collision occured?

Answer (score 0):

When you detect an intersection between two collision objects, you need to make a decision about how you're going to counteract the overlap (as I'm sure you figured out).  However, how one does this is a bit trickier than simply "pushing" them to one side (as you've done in your code).  What you likely want to do is to have a counter-force to the applied force, so to speak.  Basically, you want to calculate the minimum translation, or the direction by which the least amount of movement would be required, to get at least ONE of the boxes to move OUT of the other one.

This is a bit more complicated than simply "put me on the right (or left, depending on how you set up your coordinates, I suppose) side of the other guy," which is more or less what your code does, now.

For a simple solution, just check if one of the colliders is closer to the left, right, top, or bottom of the other.  To do this, you can simply take the collision intersection position  and check the relative distance between that point and the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates relative to one of the colliders, then move the one or both of the sprites, accordingly.

Ex:
[Edit]  After reviewing my previous answer for this, I realized you would need to calculate the overlap of the boxes, which would make it much easier to accomplish this all like so:

```
float minX = min(sprite0.boundingBox.maxX, sprite1.boundingBox.maxX);// Minimum of the boxes' right-side points (top right and bottom right) x coordinates
float minY = min(sprite0.boundingBox.maxY, sprite1.boundingBox.maxY);// Minimum of the boxes' top-side points (top left and top right) y coordinates

float maxX = max(sprite0.boundingBox.minX, sprite1.boundingBox.minX);// Maximum of the boxes' left-side points (top left and bottom left) x coordinates
float maxY = max(sprite0.boundingBox.minY, sprite1.boundingBox.minY);// Maximum of the boxes' bottom-side points (bottom left and bottom right) y coordinates

float distHoriz = minX - maxX;// The horizontal intersection distance
float distVert = minY - maxY;// The vertical instersection distance

// If the boxes are overlapping less on the horizontal axis than the vertical axis,
// move one of the sprites (in this case, sprite0) in the opposite direction of the
// x-axis overlap
if(abs(distHoriz) < abs(distVert))
{
    sprite0.x -= distHoriz;
}
// Else, move one of the sprites (again, I just decided to use sprite0 here,
// arbitrarily) in the opposite direction of the y-axis overlap
else
{
    sprite0.y -= distVert;
}
```

To further clarify (beyond the comments), what we're basically doing here is checking the distance between the overlapping lines.  For example:

```
Box 0 x-axis  xmin0|------------------|xmax0
Box 1 x-axis                xmin1|----------------------|xmax1
                                 |----|<-- Overlap (xmax0 - xmin1)
```

Notice that the minimum from the two bounding boxes that is used for the overlap is the maximum among the two minima (xmin0 and xmin1), and the maximum that is used for the overlap is the minimum among the two maxima (xmax0 and xmax1).

The y-axis calculation works exactly the same way.  Once we have both axes, we simply check to see which one has a lower absolute value (which distance is shorter) and move along that distance to counteract the intersection.

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? I initially set enemyMob[0] .x to 500 and .y to 200 and enemyMob[1] .x to 800 and .y to 200 and enemyMob[1] just flies off above without intersecting at all. Here's my code seen as I can't post code here in comments, boundingBox.Width is the width of the sprite as the X co. is in top left: http://pastebin.com/fTLsiU6d

Comment: I'm quite positive it will work, as long as you've got something comparable to those methods/functions in the pseudo code I used.  It would be easiest if they were axis-aligned (by easiest, I mean that you wouldn't need to re-calculate the max/min positions on the bounding boxes).  I'll add some more detail for clarity.

Comment: Admittedly I did need to make one more minor correction that I had mixed up, which was the min-max deal.  You need to subtract the maximum of the two minima from the minimum of the two maxima (Look to the answer for a more detailed explanation).